# Tomcat 7,8,9 web.xml redirect to WSDL

Tags: tomcat, wsdl

Spec : Jdk1.7,TOMCAT 7,8,9

Question : How to redirect to a specified WSDL using the `"<welcome-file>"` in Tomcat - web.xml

Also does this work in Tomcat / WebLogic / JBoss Containers ?